# How to get the value of a function to use on end of GetElementByID.SRC

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random, getelementbyid

I've got a function that picks a random image out of the three in the array, however I want to display one of the 3 images randomly at the end of the GetElementByID.SRC code so it randomly picks a picture and shows it.

I'm struggling to see why this isn't working as I've read other things online that have led me to this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQVtJ.png)

The image above is what I'm getting, but the sources are correct from what I can tell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eqfu.png)

```js
// Function to play each episode
function playEpisode() {

let lowestPlayer = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < players; i++) { // Loop through each player 
    let totalStats = stamina + speed + strength; // Calculate total combined stats
    if (totalStats < lowestPlayer) { // Compare total combined stats to the lowest score and update if needed
        lowestPlayer = totalStats;
        break;
    }
}

let lowestPlayerCastMember = castMembers[lowestPlayer];
let randomSceneNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * scenes.length);

gameStarted = true;

var img = ["./images/s1oc.webp", "./images/garagekill.gif", "./images/highschoolmurder.gif"]

function imgRandom (imgArr) {
    
    return imgArr[Math.floor(Math.random(img) * imgArr.length)];
}

document.getElementById("mainbox").innerHTML = scenes[randomSceneNumber];
document.getElementById("scenebox").src = imgRandom(img);
document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "The Phone Rings at " + lowestPlayerCastMember + " answers the phone";

assignObjects();
triggerEvent(); 
eliminateOne();
removeDeadCast();
increaseSuspicion();    
episodecount++; // Increment episode count

console.log("Episode after Opening Scene Count " + episodecount);
}
```

Expected it to work, but it doesn't and there's no sign of issue.

EDIT: I HAVE CHANGED THE SCRIPT AS I'VE FIXED IT NOW - The file format was wrong and not added to the array and the Math.random was written in lowercase for the M.

Comment: `math.random(img)` this needs to be `Math.random(img)`. What is the error that you get?

Comment: I've fixed that, however I'm still having issues - I've update the post above to show the screenshot

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Learn to use the developer  tools. You have a 404 there so that means the path is not correct for some image on the page.

Comment: I've fixed it now - will update the above code

Comment: `Math.random(img)` should be `Math.random()` You have a bunch of other variables that are not defined so not sure if it is an error or you have not shown all the code.

Comment: Sorry, there's a lot of code, but I have quite a lot of variables above this code. Thank you all for the help, I'm still quite new to stackflow and the whole thing, but hopefully I can get better :)

Answer (score 0):

// Function to play each episode
function playEpisode() {

```
let lowestPlayer = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < players; i++) { // Loop through each player 
    let totalStats = stamina + speed + strength; // Calculate total combined stats
    if (totalStats < lowestPlayer) { // Compare total combined stats to the lowest score and update if needed
        lowestPlayer = totalStats;
        break;
    }
}

let lowestPlayerCastMember = castMembers[lowestPlayer];
let randomSceneNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * scenes.length);

gameStarted = true;

var img = ["./images/s1oc.webp", "./images/garagekill.gif", "./images/highschoolmurder.gif"]

function imgRandom (imgArr) {
    
    return imgArr[Math.floor(Math.random(img) * imgArr.length)];
}

document.getElementById("mainbox").innerHTML = scenes[randomSceneNumber];
document.getElementById("scenebox").src = imgRandom(img);
document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "The Phone Rings at " + lowestPlayerCastMember + " answers the phone";

assignObjects();
triggerEvent(); 
eliminateOne();
removeDeadCast();
increaseSuspicion();    
episodecount++; // Increment episode count

console.log("Episode after Opening Scene Count " + episodecount);
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).